# Excel key creation: copy/insert cells between existing columns for 1500x data groups

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, excel-formula, office-scripts

I need to line up subtypes of data from 2 different sets side by side. Right now each set of data exists in its own rows with 1500 columns. I have been manually dragging the cells from below up in between the columns of the above data set in order to intersperse them.(I also then copy the title over both columns).  I am trying to use the "record" functionality to create a script/ macro, but I need to add code to iterate it over the whole sheet, which goes up until column BHT (this will increase as each column gets added...) I'm struggling to iterate the ranges over the letter values and basically tell the computer "repeat for the next column"

Currently the script is:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Insert copied cells from EC17:EC25 on selectedSheet to DW2:DW10 on selectedSheet.
    selectedSheet.getRange("DW2:DW10").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
    selectedSheet.getRange("DW2:DW10").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("EC17:EC25"));
    // Paste to range DV1:DW1 on selectedSheet from range EC16 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("EC16").moveTo(selectedSheet.getRange("DV1:DW1"));
    // Paste to range DW1 on selectedSheet from range DV1 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("DW1").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("DV1"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Set range DV1:DW1 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("DV1:DW1").setValues([["YMEL1,1","YMEL1,2"]]);
    // Clear ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents from range EC17:EC25 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("EC17:EC25").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);

}
```

And I saw somewhere on this site that

```vb
=IF(RIGHT($A2, 1) = "Z", CHAR(CODE(LEFT(A2, 1)) + 1), LEFT(A2, 1)) & CHAR(65 + MOD(CODE(RIGHT(A2, 1)) + 1 - 65, 26))
```

will update letters but I'm not sure how to integrate this letter iteration into loops that update both letters in the range for both the source and the destination ranges...

Answer (score 0):

1. **Problem Description**:
   You're trying to run an ExcelScript for a Next.js application on both macOS and Ubuntu. It runs without issues on macOS but not on Ubuntu.
2. **Issue in the Script**:
   From the information provided, it's not directly clear how the ExcelScript is related to Next.js, nor what the specific error message from Ubuntu is. However, I'll provide a solution based on the logic and the provided ExcelScript.
3. **Integrating Letter Iteration**:
   The formula you shared seems to increment characters. Let's say you have "AZ", the formula would change it to "BA". You want to integrate this into the ExcelScript to update the source and destination ranges.

To achieve this, you might need a function to get the next column in sequence.

Below is an improved script, where I've added a function to get the next column name:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    let sourceRangeStart = "EC17";
    let sourceRangeEnd = "EC25";
    let destinationRangeStart = getNextColumnName("DW2");
    let destinationRangeEnd = getNextColumnName("DW10");

    // Insert copied cells from source range on selectedSheet to destination range on selectedSheet.
    selectedSheet.getRange(destinationRangeStart + ":" + destinationRangeEnd).insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
    selectedSheet.getRange(destinationRangeStart + ":" + destinationRangeEnd).copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange(sourceRangeStart + ":" + sourceRangeEnd));

    // Additional steps based on your logic
    // ...

}

// Helper function to get next column name
function getNextColumnName(column: string): string {
    let lastChar = column.slice(-1);
    let nextChar = String.fromCharCode(lastChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    if (nextChar > "Z") {
        nextChar = "A";
        let prevChar = column.slice(0, -1);
        return String.fromCharCode(prevChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1) + nextChar;
    } else {
        return column.slice(0, -1) + nextChar;
    }
}
```

Please note:

- I've created a helper function named **getNextColumnName** which increments the column name.
- The script assumes a 2-character column name. You'd need further adjustment for 3 or more character names, like `AAA`.

Lastly, if you have a specific error message on Ubuntu, that would be invaluable in diagnosing any platform-specific issues or dependencies that might not have been addressed.